# How can I avoid duplicate switch statements

Tags: c#, algorithm, design-patterns

I have an enum of phone conditions. At one point in my application I need to update a price based on the condition of the phone, e.g.

```
switch (condition)
{
    case Condition.Good:
        price = goodPrice;
        break;
    case Condition.ScreenCrack:
        price = screenCrackPrice;
        break;
    case Condition.CameraCrack:
        price = cameraCrackPrice;
        break;
    case Condition.BadBattery:
        price = badBatteryPrice;
        break;
    case Condition.ScreenCrack | Condition.CameraCrack:
        price = screenCrackCameraCrackPrice;
        break;
    case Condition.ScreenCrack | Condition.BadBattery:
        price = screenCrackBadBatteryPrice;
        break;
    case Condition.CameraCrack | Condition.BadBattery:
        price = cameraCrackBadBatteryPrice;
        break;
case Condition.ScreenCrack | Condition.CameraCrack | Condition.BadBattery:
        price = screenCrackCameraCrackBadBatteryPrice;
        break;
}
```

Later on, the user may want to edit the price associated with that same condition. How can I do this without making another switch statement?

Comment: Why not use an object with multiple properties, like `Name` and `Price`? Then it's just `price += condition.Price`, and then when you want to change the price you only change it in one place. Eventually, this could be saved in a DB instead of hard-coded objects.

Comment: @Origin That is what I thought I should do. I'll try and implement it right now.

Comment: Or, create a `Dictionary<Condition, decimal>` that you initialize with your price list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use an object with multiple properties, like Name and Price? Then it's just `price += condition.Price`, and then when you want to change the price you only change it in one place. Eventually, this could be saved in a DB instead of hard-coded objects.